# Can I avoid using $scope and have user actions set AngularJS dirty bit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, dirty-data

I have a table of settings (e.g., check boxes) on a form and the user has the ability to add and remove table rows.  `theForm.$dirty` gets set if the user changes a setting (e.g., checks or unchecks a check box) but not if a row is added to or removed from the table.  I have an example at https://plnkr.co/edit/sOXFnZjpkrcExvxGsEVg

I'm a relatively new Angular developer but I've been cautioned that it is not a best practice to reference `$scope` if one can avoid it.  I *think* that in this case, I could make the controller depend on `$scope` then invoke `$scope.theForm.$setDirty()` in the functions which modify the table.  I'm not sure if that is my only recourse or if there's a better approach.

Comment: can't view your plnkr atm, but what is the reason you want to know if the form is dirty?

Comment: One immediate use is to enable or disable a Save button.

Comment: makes sense. The accepted answer does what you need (keeps $scope out of the controller), but you asked if there is a 'better' approach. You may consider thinking about asking if your model is dirty instead of/in addition to asking if your form is dirty. I assume your table DOM is driven by some sort of model collection (ng-repeat over a collection). If so, you could also bind a controller method (isModelDirty) to ng-disabled and ask if your model collection has changed or not. Just a thought...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put form to controller:

```
form name="vm.testForm"
```

But there is nothing bad if controller depends on scope.

Comment: If you plan on migrating to angular 2 or 4, then it's best to get out of using $scope.  At least that's what initial reading led me to believe.

Comment: Putting the controller name in the `name` of the form (adding `vm.` at the start) does what I want.  Thanks, Petr!